# How to put variable inside a innerHTML tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var item = document.getElementById('drpItem').value;
var createDiv = document.createElement('createDiv');

createDiv.className = 'row';

createDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="name" value="item" />
```

Comment: in creatDiv.innerHTML i have to use item variable with some string. How can i do that?

Comment: `'<input type="text" name="name" value="'+item+'" />`. Please read Javascript string concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this  .`'string'+variable+'string'`

```
createDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="name" value="'+item+'" />
```